# How can I update p:photoCam to the lastest version but keep my primefaces in 6.1.RC2?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

The p:photocam version for this version of primefaces (6.1.RC2) doesn't work very well, and I need to update it, but due to other reasons I can't update the primefaces.

It is possible?

Thank you all

Comment: This is a good moment to upgrade PrimeFaces and benefit from security updates. See https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-8-0-has-landed/

Comment: I know, but unfortunately I can't perform this update for now

Comment: Then at least update to 6.1 full release or 6.2...

Answer (score 3):

OK attempt this at your own risk but do the following if you must stay on 6.1.

1. Download PrimeFaces 8.0 JAR.
2. Unzip the JAR and find the file \META-INF\resources\primefaces\photocam\photocam.js
3. Now take the photocam.js from step # 2 and replace it in your PrimeFaces 6.1 JAR in the same location and zip up the 6.1 JAR again.

That should do it but I will not guarantee it will work.

Comment: I think you can also override that resource by simply adding it to your project at the same location

Comment: I'll try the both method! Thank you guys!